# C# 5.0 Visual Studio Code Intellisense System.IO

Tags: c#, intellisense, c#-5.0

[image: Visual Studio Code]

Visual Studio Code tells me the type or namespace 'DirectoryInfo' could not be found. Oddly enough though `using System.IO;` is indeed included. I have gone as far as adding it to the frameworks.

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
```

Now funny thing is I can run this just fine without a hitch of problems. Its like the Intellisense isn't correct. Any ideas as to why I am getting this red squiggly?

Comment: When you say you can "run this just fine" - have you tried running it under dnxcore50 instead of under dnx451?

Comment: Ah I bet it targeted 451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` are in the `System.IO` namespace, in the DNX world they're in the `System.IO.FileSystem` assembly. So you need to add a dependency of:

```
"System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1-beta-23302"
```